# jquery selection change event and display a div

Tags: jquery

i have a selection called .select_payment and a div called #billing
what im trying to do is when the user selects the selection and its value equals "credit"
i want the billing div to be displayed. it is hidden by default. 
this is what i tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select_payment").change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "credit")
            {
                $("#billilng").css('display','block');
            }
        });
    });
```

when i select the option called credit, nothing happends.

Comment: typo? `#billilng` should be `#billing`?

Comment: You've got a typo: "#billilng" should be "#billing". Also, you say you have something "called .select_payment", but do you mean you have a select element with a class of "select_payment"? (Because that's what your code thinks.) Finally, when you say "hidden", do you mean "display:none" or "visibility:hidden"?

Comment: lol, i guess that was it thanks, how do i hide after its visible again? something like toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With typo fixed, and a couple of lines added for testing, this works for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#billing").css('display','none');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select_payment").change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "credit"){
                $("#billing").css('display','block');
            } else {
                $("#billing").css('display','none');
            }
        });
    });

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select name='payment_type' class='select_payment' >
    <option value='credit'>credit</option>
    <option value='debit'>debit</option>    
</select>
<div id='billing'>This is the billing div</div>
</body>
</html>
```